# Not recognizing a type as an associated type of a monad inside a transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm playing around with OpenGL in general and Haskell library named GPipe in particular. I have a monad transformer stack with `IO` at the bottom, then the `ContextT` transformer from the library, then a `StateT` because some state is required, and finally a `newtype Processor` because simple `type` would produce hideous error messages for such a stack. That's the general idea. However, the code below doesn't typecheck:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Main where

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Except

import qualified "GPipe" Graphics.GPipe as GP
import qualified "GPipe-GLFW" Graphics.GPipe.Context.GLFW as GLFW

---- State and Processor types ----

class ArtState os as | as -> os where
    event :: GP.ContextHandler ctx => as -> Processor ctx os (as, Maybe e)
    present :: GP.ContextHandler ctx => as -> Processor ctx os as
    window :: Lens' as (WindowType os)

data ProgramState = ProgramState

newtype GP.ContextHandler ctx => Processor ctx os a = Processor {
    runProcessor :: StateT ProgramState (GP.ContextT ctx os IO) a
}

---- MenuArt things ----

type WindowType os = GP.Window os GP.RGBFloat GP.Depth

data MenuArt os = MenuArt {
    _maWindow :: WindowType os
}

makeLenses ''MenuArt

instance ArtState os (MenuArt os) where
    event ms = Processor $ return (ms, Nothing)
    present ms = Processor $ return ms
    window = maWindow

initMenuArt :: (ArtState os a, GP.ContextHandler ctx) =>
       Maybe a 
    -> Processor ctx os (Either String (MenuArt os))
initMenuArt Nothing = Processor $ do
    win <- lift $ GP.newWindow (GP.WindowFormatColorDepth GP.RGB8 GP.Depth16)
                               (GLFW.defaultWindowConfig "foobar")
    return $ Right $ MenuArt {
        _maWindow = win
    }
initMenuArt (Just from) = Processor $ do
    return $ Right $ MenuArt {
        _maWindow = from ^. window
    }

---- events ----

data UserEvent = CloseWindow
```

The error message is as follows:

```
/tmp/testing/app/Main.hs:49:33: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘GP.WindowParameters ctx’
                  with actual type ‘GLFW.WindowConfig’
    • In the second argument of ‘GP.newWindow’, namely
        ‘(GLFW.defaultWindowConfig "foobar")’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘GP.newWindow
           (GP.WindowFormatColorDepth GP.RGB8 GP.Depth16)
           (GLFW.defaultWindowConfig "foobar")’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        win <- lift
                 $ GP.newWindow
                     (GP.WindowFormatColorDepth GP.RGB8 GP.Depth16)
                     (GLFW.defaultWindowConfig "foobar")
    • Relevant bindings include
        initMenuArt :: Maybe a
                       -> Processor ctx os (Either String (MenuArt os))
          (bound at app/Main.hs:47:1)
   |
49 |                                (GLFW.defaultWindowConfig "foobar")
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From what I could understand, the `newWindow` expects a `WindowParameters ctx` as its second argument, which is an associated type for the `ContextHandler` class. But the compiler doesn't see that `GLFW.WindowConfig` is `WindowParameters` for this stack for some reason. Throwing away `StateT` and `Processor` from the stack (as in the tutorial I'm working through) works, this compiles:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  GP.runContextT GLFW.defaultHandleConfig $ do
    win <- GP.newWindow (GP.WindowFormatColor GP.RGB8) (GLFW.defaultWindowConfig "foobar")
    return ()
  return ()
```

I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initMenuArt` is using `GLFW.defaultWindowConfig`, which is a GLFW function.

`GPipe` defines an interface parameterized by a `ctx` type, and `GPipe-GLFW` implements that interface by instantiating `ctx` with `GLFW.Handle`.

Thus `initMenuArt` should be specialized accordingly:

```
initMenuArt
    :: (ArtState os a)
    => Maybe a 
    -> Processor GLFW.Handle os (Either String (MenuArt os))
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I hope I don't bother you too much with my stupid questions.

Comment: No problem! These are very good questions, both in matter and form.